# Need list of JavaWS cache files for my application

Tags: java, caching, download, java-web-start

We have an application that uses JavaWS to launch. I know the JARs listed in the JNLP content are stored in the client deployment cache. Is there a way for my application to get the list of the actual cache files used to launch it?

I printed out the classpath: c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre7\lib\deploy.jar

I used Java VisualVM to inspect the application's properties but no joy to be found.

Comment: *"Need list of JavaWS cache files for my application"*  ..Why?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for my application to get the list of the actual cache files used to launch it?

Sure. Use the JNLP API's [`DownloadService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html) can provide that.

> `DownloadService` service allows an application to control how its own resources are cached, to determine **which of its resources are currently cached,** to force resources to be cached, and to remove resources from the cache. The JNLP Client is responsible for providing a specific implementation of this service.